# Group Dart await call into Single Statement

Tags: flutter, dart

Is it possible to group lines of await calls? So for example i have lines of code like below:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
await preferences.setString("id", user.id);
await preferences.setString("first_name", user.firstName);
await preferences.setString("last_name", user.lastName);
```

So can i group this 3 `await` into single call?

Comment: check `Future.wait()`

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do that? There are different methods (or none at all) depending on what you want to achieve.